# Regular expression for duplicating conditions in every if statement

Tags: regex

I'm writing a Regular Expression in Notepad++ to duplicate and modify certain if conditions.

For instance:

if (variable1 == "") should become

**if (variable1 == "" or len(variable1) == 0)**

The key things I need to match are the variable names until the =="" so I can duplicate them for the or condition

I had the following expression:

```
[A-Za-z0-9()]*?\s*==\s*""
```

But it fails when there is no white space between the If and the parentheses

https://regex101.com/r/Beyumi/3

I believe the following lines should cover most cases:

```
If (Trim(var1) == "" And var2 == "") 
    /*Then do something*
ElseIf(var3 == "" And var4 == "" And Trim(var5)=="") Then
/*block of code*/
ElseIf var6 ==""
```

The expression should be able to match:

1. Trim(var1) == ""
2. var2 == ""
3. var3 == ""
4. var4 == ""
5. Trim(var5)==""
6. var6 ==""

*Note: In the event of And statements, I can manually add the necessary parentheses when adding the 'or' condition*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
((\w+|trim\(\w+\))\s*==\s*"")
```

and replace it with this,

```
(\1 or len(\2) == 0)
```

Notice, I've enabled case insensitive matching and `(\w+|trim\(\w+\))` part matches either plain variable using `\w+` or matches `trim(variablename)` using `trim\(\w+\)` and captures it in group2, where `\s*` around `==` takes care of optional whitespaces and whole group is captured in parenthesis so it can be replaced with current expression and additionally with `or len(\2) == 0` and whole of it surrounded by parenthesis for appropriate grouping due to `and` condition.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Beyumi/4)**

Comment: Thank you so much!! This appears to be working really well thus far. I was over-complicating it by not realizing that it was always either a trim or the actual variable before the == and nothing else even in the actual data. I'm going to run a few more tests on my larger files now.

Comment: There are a few edge cases like Array(x)=="" or Trim(Array(x))=="". Is there an easy way to account for those in the regex that you sent over? I thought of adding them as 3rd and 4th alternatives

Comment: @Sid: Glad it helped you. Yes if you just want to also support `Array(x)` kind of expression, it is better to just support this with two more alternations. But in case you want to support such kind of functions in general, I can help you with a better generalized approach so every time you want to support a function, you don't have to add it into alternations. For just supporting that `Array(x)` you can use. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Beyumi/5)